# Must a predicate $P(x)$ be dependent on its variables?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Must a predicate $P(x)$ be dependent on its variables?

Suppose we have a function $P(x)$ which returns either true or false irrespective of the value of $x$.  Is this still a predicate?  Is it valid to write $P(x)$ when $x$ is independent of $P$?

I imagine $P$ isn't a predicate when written such; or it's a "type error" to even write $P(x)$ when $x$ is independent of $P$ e.g. a bit like saying:

"$35$ degrees centigrade is tall"

Comment: Yes; we can consider e.g. the predicate $P(x) := (x \ge 0)$ for *natural* numbers: it is always TRUE.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA if $P:\Bbb{Z}\to\{\text{true,false}\}$ then your answer is kind of obvious. I would accept $P$ is a predicate function without question. But I might argue $P$ isn't independent of $x\in\Bbb{Z}$ in that case.  If your $P$ is $P:\Bbb{N}\to\{\text{true}\}$ then this is as you say independent of $x$ for the natural numbers $x\in\Bbb{N}$, but is it still a predicate function?

Comment: *Predicate* symbols (consider the unary case, for simplicity) are syntactical objects, interpreted with subsets of the domain. Thus, a unary predicate symbol is defined with a "slot" to be filled by an argument (usually written $P(x)$); in this sense, the "dependency" is built in into the symbol.

Comment: A "constant" predicate, i.e. one that is always TRUE (or FALSE) is not different in principle. Compare the numerical function $f(x)=x^2$ with the constant function $g(x)=1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard convention is to write $P(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ as a metanotation for a **syntactic** predicate whose free variables are contained in $\{x_1, \ldots, x_n\}$. The formulas $x = x$, $x \neq x$, $x \neq 1$ and $1 = 1$ are all perfectly good possibilities for $P(x)$ under this convention even though only one of them has a truth value that depends on the value of $x$. Whether $P(x)$ actually depends on $x$ is a **semantic** issue and the use of the notation $P(x)$ is neutral about the existence of an actual semantic dependency.

Answer (score 3):

Does $f(x)=3$ not define a function from numbers to numbers? Why would it be any different for a function from numbers, say, to truth values?

Comment: The very meaning of being predicate upon something implies **dependency of truth and falsehood upon the input variable**. I was wondering if this implication was necessarily inherent in the mathematical definition of a predicate function... so can the function $P:X\to\{\text{true}\}: P(x)=\text{true}\forall x\in{X}$ be considered a predicate.

Comment: Unless you were working in a higher-order logic, I'd consider it an interpretation of a predicate, and the codomain can be larger than the range, i.e. I would still write $P:X\to\{\text{true},\text{false}\}$, but, yes, it can and in fact it better be or else we'll have a hard time modeling predicates that hold for all $X$. If you meant this syntactically then, as Rob Arthan states, there is generally no requirement that the definition of a predicate $P(x)$ actually has $x$ to occur in it, just as for functions. Constantly "true" or "false" predicates are just "degenerate" cases of dependency.